# Elements in Array List to appear on a new line

Tags: java, string, user-interface, arraylist, joptionpane

My ArrayList is adding a `String` each time it loops, however it shows up on one big line. How do I make it to where each `String` shows up on a new line in JOptionPane as it loops?

Here is my report method:

```
public String report()
    {
        return(name + "\t" + height + " inches\t" + weight + " pounds\tBMI: "
                + df.format(bmiValue()) + "\t" + bmiStatus() );
    }
```

And here is the code with the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

        if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File f = choose.getSelectedFile();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(f));
            int l = scanner.nextInt();

            for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            {
               int height = s.nextInt();
               int weight = s.nextInt();
               String name = s.nextLine();

               BmiRecord r = new BmiRecord(name, height, weight);
               a.add(r.report());
            } 

            confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, a, "BMI Calc", 
           JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your report() function should be:

```
public String report()
{
    return(name + "\t" + height + " inches\t" + weight + " pounds\tBMI: "
            + df.format(bmiValue()) + "\t" + bmiStatus() + "\n");
}
```

Notice I added the `\n` which adds a new line to the end of the String returned from the report() function.

Also `ArrayList a = new ArrayList();` should be changed to `ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();` Using the String parameter for the ArrayList ensures type safety as the ArrayList can only hold String objects where as your ArrayList is a raw type that can hold any object and is not type safe.